# SQL Server trigger before insert or update depend on value

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, triggers

Is it possible to check a column value, then before insert or update change other records value?

I'll explain more: I have table as below:

```
CREATE DATABASE pics
GO

CREATE TABLE tel
(
    [id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [number] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [active] [bit]                                  
)
```

I need to know active tel number, I need if current record (insert or update) is True in `active` column, other records `active` column set to False,

I mean when

1. insert or update a record and
2. current record active value is True

then set all other records `active` column to False.

Is it possible?

Comment: You can't create `before insert` trigger, but you can create `instead of insert` trigger and do whatever you want before actual insertion in this trigger.

Comment: What is the *current* record - how do you define that? A SQL Server trigger is fired **once per statement** - if that `INSERT` or `UPDATE` affected multiple rows - which of those rows is your *current* row ???

Comment: If you can define the logic of your goal, the rest is simple SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check following [SQL trigger](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-trigger-example-in-sql-server-2008.aspx)

```
select * from tel
/*
insert into tel select 'kodyaz','123456789',1
insert into tel select 'eralper','45688',1
insert into tel select 'sql','7955528',1
insert into tel values ('SQLServer','0152222',1),('SQL2016','20162016',1)
*/
go
create trigger tr_tel_active on tel after update, insert
as
begin
    if exists (
        select * from inserted where active = 1
    )
    update tel 
    set active = 0
    where 
        id not in (
            select id from inserted where active = 1
        ) and active = 1
end
go
```

Please note that the most common error made by developers about triggers is that we always think each insert or update statement will work only for one record. This is not true.
For example, one of my insert statements creates 2 rows at the same time.

What this trigger does is that: It updates all active rows to deactive statement if at least there is one active row is inserted or updated

Please test before deploying to productive

Comment: it's work perfect, i must check and understand what you write, can you direct me to a simple tutorial for trigger,

Comment: In trigger execution, you have two tables "inserted" and "deleted" which reflect the new and old version of the row. If you are updating a row, both inserted and deleted tables have data. Otherwise when using Insert or Delete commands, one of the above tables is empty. You can build your logic using these tables data. Please refer to link http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-trigger-example-in-sql-server-2008.aspx for more detail. And this is important, always create a set based logic. Variables that can store single values are very dangerous and cause errors in your data integrity

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure did i understand you well, but if you want to do some checks before some record is inserted into table by using trigger then you can use Instead of trigger type.

Behavior and syntax is similar to after trigger, the main difference is that you can say instead of inserting this row => do this... and with after trigger logic is insert row => do this....

Comment: thanks @MiroslavStojakovic for your reply, i need first check, if activity is true, change other records activity to false, otherwise, insert or update